# How to loop throw more then one request id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbml, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is this method depreciated?

```
FB.api("/?ids=" + response.request_ids, callback);
```

It used to work but now it doesn't.

I want to get all the data from all the requestIds I received using JavaScript.

For one requestId this method is working well:

```
FB.api('/' + requestId, function (response)
```

but what if I have more the one requestId?

Answer (score 0):

Try querying /me/apprequests instead. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fapprequests

Comment: it's not working. I'm getting an empty result after I've sent myself an invite from another user.

Comment: Have you checked that the sending of the request worked (checked out the return data from the dialog)? What kind of access token are you using?